# Delphi 2010 and Generics

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I am trying to do somenthing like the following:

```
type
  IExemplo<Generic> = interface
    function GetGenerico: Generic;    
  end;

  TClassA<Generic> = class(TComponent, IExemplo<Generic>)
    function GetGenerico: Generic; virtual;
    function GetInterface: IExemplo<Generic>; virtual;
  end;

  TClassB = class(TClassA<string>)
    function GetGenerico: string; override;
    function GetInterface: IExemplo<string>; override;
  end;
```

In other words, I create an interface that has some Generics, a base class to implement the interface, and finally a derived class to implement the base class.

But, in the line

```
function GetInterface: IExemplo<string>; override;
```

I am getting a syntax error.

My goal is for `TClassB` to no longer have the Generic attribute, at this point its type has already been properly set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is valid and compiles in later versions of Delphi. Indeed, it compiles for me with Delphi 2010, and so I wonder if you perhaps have not installed [all the updates that are available for Delphi 2010](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40204/).

Delphi generics were riddled with defects in the early releases. By some distance, the most pragmatic approach is for you to upgrade to a modern version of Delphi in order to escape the tyranny of these defects. Yes, you may get around the problem by installing updates to Delphi 2010, but I am sure that you will encounter other problems with generics before long.